# Synchronization and Replication

Tags: sync, replication

Depending upon many scenarios, we see Synchronization and Replication frequently.

What are the differences between Synchronization and Replication?

Regards

InTech

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_(computer_science)

Replication: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_(computing)

It seems to me that **Synchronization** is removing the differences between the copies, like if you had two identical copies, one of them has been changed later from another.

**Replication** is a mechanism of synchronization different copies of one object. In most cases it assumes copy of data from one source to another (or others).

Here is an example of explanation of differences between them: https://network.informatica.com/thread/52613

" Data **Replication** allows you to **copy** multiple tables from the same source and do incremental loads (only copying new or updated data on subsequent runs of the same task).

Data **Syncronization** allows you to **transform** data with field expressions and lookups. "